# ContentView notification?

Tags: android, view, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TextView doesn't display all the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236991/textview-doesnt-display-all-the-text)

Hi! How can I set for the contentview of my notification to see all the text I put? I have this code :

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.proba);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif1,"Today,you must go for shopping for your list '" + list + "'. "+ "Don't forget!!!"+"\n"+"You must buy "+s);
notification.contentView = contentView;
```

where s is a `StringBuilder`, and I see only a part of the text. What should I do?Please help