# TextView doesn't display all the text

Tags: android, notifications

In my app I can't see in my notification all the text I display. I put \n but this doesn't help me and I don't understand why.

this is proba.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="3dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/notif" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code :

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.proba);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif,
                "Today,you must go for shopping for your list '" + list + "'. "
                        + "Don't forget!!!" + "\n" + "You must buy :" + "\n"
                        + s.toString() + "\n");
        notification.contentView = contentView;
```

where in s is a StringBuilder and in s I have something like this :" onions 1kg,tomatoes 2 kg,..."

Comment: no idea why I have this problem? :(

Answer (score 0):

A stringBuilder is not a string. Use `s.toString()` to actually get a string.

Comment: I put s.toString() but that doesn't change with nothing my notification. I see only a part of the text.

Comment: What part do you see? Why are you even using a stringbuilder if you just add several strings together in the textview. The entire idea of a stringbuilder is that you don't have to do that.

Comment: I see :" Today,you must go for shopping for your list 'list'.Don't forget!!!You must buy onions 1 kg ". In s I put the items of a shoppinglist. I used StringBuilder for putting all the items in a single variable. So, in s I have more items, but I see only the first one and a part of the second one.

Comment: Is your view big enough to fit all the text in? What happens if you output the string trought Log?

Comment: I second Nallath, what's the layout file for `R.layout.proba`? Is the `TextView`'s layout_height `wrap_content`?

Comment: that's the problem that my view is not big enough to fill all the text in. Can I make it bigger?

Comment: This is proba.xml : <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="3dp">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/notif1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: I still can't see all the text,even if I put more \n....I have no idea where can be the problem.

Comment: post a screenshot. where is the string cut? what part of the string is displayed, what is missing? please elaborate your questions better, my glass bowl is not available at present. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `TextView`s are single-line ([TextView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine)). You can make them multi-line by adding `android:singleLine="false"` to your `proba.xml`.